# Unable to get an Access token using a named credential and getting a State not Send OAuth Error

Tags: oauth2, tooling-api, oauth, accesstoken

I am trying to get SF access token using a named credential as that is the secure way as mention [here](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.perm_uapa_create_a_named_credential.htm&type=5):

I am basically unable to login successfully and get the following error :

```
No_Oauth_State&ErrorDescription=State+was+not+sent+back
```

I have verified that consumer secret and key are entered right in auth provider.

My connected app oauth settings:
[image]

My Named Credential:
[image]

My authorization provider:

[image]

In my Apex:

```
Http h = new Http();
        HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
        req.setEndpoint('callout:Tooling_API_Credential');
        req.setMethod('POST');
        HttpResponse res = h.send(req);
```

I am able to authenticate the named credential.
When I run it I am getting null for access token and in my error logs I see:

```
16:33:18.0 (26293187)|CALLOUT_REQUEST|[61]|System.HttpRequest[Endpoint=callout:Tooling_API_Credential, Method=POST]
16:33:18.119 (119057588)|NAMED_CREDENTIAL_REQUEST|NamedCallout[Named Credential Id=someID, Named Credential Name=Tooling_API_Credential, Endpoint=https://my-org.sandbox.my.salesforce.com/services/authcallback/SF_Auth_Provider, Method=POST, External Credential Type=EXTERNAL, HTTP Header Authorization=**Method: Bearer - Credential: Not set**, Content-Type=null, Request Size bytes=95, Retry on 401=True]
16:33:18.119 (119872673)|NAMED_CREDENTIAL_RESPONSE|NamedCallout[Named Credential Id=someID, Named Credential Name=Tooling_API_Credential, Status Code=302, Content-Type=null, Response Size bytes=0, Overall Callout Time ms=80, Connect Time ms=47
16:33:18.0 (126697917)|CALLOUT_RESPONSE|[61]|System.HttpResponse[Status=Found, StatusCode=302]
16:33:18.0 (126727368)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[61]|Bytes:9
16:33:18.0 (126762390)|VARIABLE_SCOPE_BEGIN|[61]|res|System.HttpResponse|true|false
16:33:18.0 (126843252)|VARIABLE_ASSIGNMENT|[61]|res|"System.HttpResponse[Status=Found, StatusCode=302]"|0x422d5269
```

I then looked at the redirect URL and seeing this:

```
identity/sso/ui/AuthorizationError?ErrorCode=No_Oauth_State&ErrorDescription=State+was+not+sent+back&Provider
```

What am I doing wrong?

Just a FYI I am able to click on the test only initialization url and see valid json.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The URL specified in the Named Credential should be the domain URL and not the entire callback URL i.e., it should be just `https://my-org.sandbox.my.salesforce.com/`.

Usually named credential should consider only the domain URL while posting the HTTP request, but your logs seems to indicate that it's posting to the entire callback URL `=https://my-org.sandbox.my.salesforce.com/services/authcallback/SF_Auth_Provider` and running into a HTTP 302 error code.

After fixing the URL, edit the Named Credential & ensure that you check the box for `Start Authentication Flow on Save`, save the named credential and run through the successful authentication.

Also, edit the `Authentication Settings for External Systems` under your personal settings. Check the box for `Start Authentication Flow on Save`, save it and run through the successful authentication.